# Datepicker picker is not working with upgraded struts jars and dependent jars

Tags: java, struts2, datepicker

I am working on an application that required struts jar upgrade. After upgrade of struts jars I found that the date picker doesn't appear as it did with the old jars.

The upgraded jars that I used are: struts2-core-2.3.16.3, struts2-tiles-2.3.14.2, xwork and freemarker.

When using struts2-tiles-2.3.16.3 it throws class not found exception for struts tiles listener class. But I can find the class (`StrutsTilesListener`) in the jar.

Please provide some assistance in usage of jars that will be compatible with struts2-core-2.3.16.3

Comment: All S2 jars must be from the same version. Post the exception that you see. Also what datepicker are you using and how it *doesn't appear as it did with the old jars*?

Comment: This can be related to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4349 when you're using Dojo plugin

Comment: @AleksandrM I used the same version of struts2 jars (2.3.16.3) but since _tiles_ jar gave the mentioned exception I reverted that jar alone back to 2.3.14.2.

FYI This is the list of upgraded jars that we are using currently:
1. struts2-core-2.3.16.3
2. struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.16.3
3. struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.3
4. commons-fileupload-1.3.1
5. commons-io-1.3.1
6. xwork-core-2.3.16.3
7. tiles-core-2.2.2
 
Regarding the datepicker: We are using <sj:datepicker>
The image that we used for the datepicker doesn't load at all when using these upgraded jars.

Comment: Ask a specific question about your problem. If your datepicker is not showing icon then add relevant code to your question and ask about that.